# Логарифм по основанию 2

Tags: математика, php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в PHP взять логарифм по основанию 2 от числа? Думал, есть стандартная функция, но, похоже, ошибся. Буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function log_bin($num){
 return log10($num)/log10(2);
//одно из свойств логарифма. Кажись, второе
}
```

Кстати.

```
log($num,2);
```

тоже никто не отменял. О_о но это начиная с 4.3

Comment: $log10(2); - знак $ лишний вроде

Comment: да, лишний
Но все равно, спасибо

Comment: Да, точняк.

Comment: Кстати, стандартная функция все же есть, если мы не берем уж очень старые версии PHP

Comment: Может быть не в тему малость. @knes, ты заострил(а) внимание на старой версии php. Скажи, сегодня, в 2012м году, разве реально наткнуться на php версии ниже 5.х ?

Comment: заостриЛ. =) 
>настоящее имя Федор
Это мужское имя, чесслово.

Дык вот: реально, еще как реально. Особенно, если человек утверждает, что нет такой стандартной функции. Знаю минимум три сайта, работающих на 4.2- версии. Фобос и деймос.

Comment: ок***еть.. окостенеть то есть) а на php 3й версии не знаешь каких-ниб проектов? интересно на это посмотреть) уже 5.4 наконец-то вышла. Интересно кстати в zf2 будут или нет использованы возможности 5.4